# Put a deadline in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

In a java program.
I need to read database, take theses data, doing some rest call,  write data in a txt file (who have an header, data and a footer).

Job start saturday night and need to finish before saturday morning. If not finish, we need to close file (write footer before) and start a new one.

I started to check some tool to do this job. Spring batch seem interesting.

I can split job with reader, process, writer.

Is there something to check if a job has reach is deadline

Job will be launch with Jentskin

Answer (score 1):

I guess you must use a scheduler for that. 
You must read from DB the end date every minute or so, and

```
       if  (endDate.compareTo(new Date())<=0)
```

than the scheduler'job must stop the batch job.

You can use Quartz